# Setup Amplify backend environment for different branch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I need to configure dev, stage, prod backend environment in different branches not in single branch. If I change in dev branch and push the code and after checking out to stage branch so the backend changes of dev branch are reflecting on stage branch which i don't want.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you change the git branch then you also need to change corresponding amplify environment by running this command

```
amplify checkout env stage
```

let's say you want to move back to your dev branch then

```
git checkout dev
amplify checkout env dev
```

(of course, assuming your amplify env name is same as git branch name )